# React-Native Expo Config mods : withDangerousMod

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to modify MainApplication.java within my React Native Expo project. Expo does not provide a built in mod so I am going to have to use withDangerousMod. Does anyone have an example / know of a repo doing this?